# Why is there a problem of insufficient funds in Opensea?

Tags: ether, metamask, nft, opensea

I am trying to pay the registration fees for setting up my Opensea account. I have currently 0.02959 Eth in my account but when I try to pay the gas fee, there is always insufficient funds problem.
[image: Current snapshot]

So, for instance at one moment the total gas fee was 0.0259 Eth and I have 0.029 Eth which is still insufficient. Do I need to have more than the max amount of Eth?

Answer (score 1):

You can set max fee with Edit button. Max fee must be lower than your balance. Because it is maximum gas you willing to pay. But if you don't have gas that you are willing to pay, of course It will give an error.